# win32com : Open method of Workbooks class failed

Tags: python, excel, automation, win32com

I am trying to run a python script which first connects to a network drive using credentials and then connects to a MS access Db file & fetches rows from a table which consists of source and destination excel file paths on network drive. Then I am executing a macro in the destination file. The batch file calling this script is running fine in interactive mode but not with a windows service or task scheduler as they're throwing below error:

```
INFO | program.py | 34 | 13-01-2023 05:47 +0100 | The network connection could not be found.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2250.


INFO | program.py | 39 | 13-01-2023 05:47 +0100 | The command completed successfully.


INFO | program.py | 47 | 13-01-2023 05:47 +0100 | Connection to MS Access DB successfull
INFO | program.py | 55 | 13-01-2023 05:47 +0100 | Fetched rows from MS Access DB
INFO | program.py | 60 | 13-01-2023 05:47 +0100 | Closed MS Access DB Connection
INFO | program.py | 79 | 13-01-2023 05:47 +0100 | Executing VBScript with source file: source.xls & destination file: dest.xlsm
ERROR | program.py | 109 | 13-01-2023 05:47 +0100 | Error Occured
ERROR | program.py | 110 | 13-01-2023 05:47 +0100 | (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', 'Open method of Workbooks class failed', 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\program\program.py", line 90, in <module>
    xl.Workbooks.Open(destination_file, ReadOnly=1)
  File "<COMObject <unknown>>", line 5, in Open
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', 'Open method of Workbooks class failed', 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)
INFO | program.py | 112 | 13-01-2023 05:47 +0100 |
```

Code related to error:

```
xl = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
# xl.Visible = True
xl.Workbooks.Open(destination_file, ReadOnly=1)
xl.Application.Run("updaterun")
xl.Application.Quit() 
del xl
```

I did not found any reference for solving this issue

Comment: I guess this has something to do with interactive logon which is not happening in case of service

Comment: What does the `destination_file` variable contain? Is it a relative or an absolute path? If you run Excel under a different account for the service it might have a different working directory for files. Maybe check the `xl.DefaultFilePath` propety to see what default folder it is using. Also, the variable `xl` is already an Application object, you don't need the `.Application` suffix

Comment: Destination file is absolute path like \\server.com\path\file. I had changed the directory in the batch file which is executed as service via nssm

Answer (score 1):

Just create the two following empty **Desktop** folders:

```
C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop

C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop
```

Don't ask me why and frankly, it's scary but it worked instantly. Found on [this thread.](https://superuser.com/questions/579900/why-cant-excel-open-a-file-when-run-from-task-scheduler) I had the same error when using the `xlwings` library in conjunction with the Windows Task Scheduler. It is not a Python issue, that much is clear.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
xl.Workbooks.Open(destination_file, ReadOnly=1,CorruptLoad=1)
```